# UITableView crashes if loaded from ContainerView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, container-view, xcode6

I've a big big problem related with a tableview (with a prototype cell made in IB) being loaded in a Container View. It loads perfectly, but when I try to tap or scroll over it just crashes with

> respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x79a96e20

If I load the ViewController where the tableview is (without being embedded in a container view) it just works, which makes me think that has something to do with tableview being unallocated after parent viewcontroller finishes its loading process.

I'm pretty new with this and it's making me mad!!

Thanks for your help.

```
(THE VIEWCONTROLLER WHICH FILLS THE CONTAINERVIEW)

class cgGameViewerController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var cgGame:UIView;  //Connected to IB ContainerView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var cgGameController=self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myIBviewController") as cgGameViewController;
        self.cgGame.addSubview(cgGameController.view);    
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }        

}


(THE VIEWCONTROLLER WHICH IS LOADED IN A CONTAINERVIEW. In IB, UITableView delegate and datasource, is attached to the viewcontroller)

class cgGameViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

        func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
            return 5;

        }

        func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
            var myCell:UITableViewCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCellInIB", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;
            return myCell;
        }
}
```

Comment: Check your tableview property , if it is weak try with **strong**.

Comment: it's SWIFT,  there are no weak or strong properties.

Comment: can you share some related code?

Comment: I added some code to the question :)

Comment: Implement [`Container Containment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) rather than simple addSubview.

Comment: Viruss mca hit the jackpot!! THANK YOU SO MUCH (I've spent almost 10h. figuring out what the hell was going on)

I could hug you now! :..)

Also Apple docs are so much cryptic...